# Можно ли оставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Когда тебя, молодого, красивого, — внезапная травма, авария или болезнь оставляет полуслепым и полупарализованным, хочешь не хочешь, а будешь искать то, что поможет смириться.

Оправдано ли тире в этом случае как авторская пунктуация, или таки убрать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тире объяснить никак нельзя. Если автор  хочет выделить определение, то можно его обособить не запятыми, а двумя тире:

*Когда тебя — **молодого и красивого** — внезапная травма, авария или болезнь оставляет полуслепым и полупарализованным, хочешь не хочешь, а будешь искать то, что поможет смириться.*